# How does Python break tie when sorting an iterable

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

I wonder how Python decides the order between two items that would be in a tie based on some specified key of a sort. For example, given: `l = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4, 5]]`, how does Python order `[1, 2, 3]` and `[2, 3, 4]` in this sort:

`sorted(l, key=lambda i: len(i), reverse=True)`

Does it keep the original (relative) order between items in a tie? Or does it order them randomly?

Comment: [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) is stable; they keep their original order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also in [wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting):

> Starting with Python 2.2, sorts are guaranteed to be stable. That
>   means that when multiple records have the same key, their original
>   order is preserved.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

> The built-in sorted() function is guaranteed to be stable. A sort is stable if it guarantees not to change the relative order of elements that compare equal — this is helpful for sorting in multiple passes (for example, sort by department, then by salary grade).