# I would like to know the difference between these codes

Tags: python-3.x

```
def myfunc(e):
  return len(e)
x=[`ab', 'aaa', 'abc','abcd',abcde']
x. sort(key=myfunc)
print(x)
```

```
Output :[`ab', 'aaa','abc','abcd','abcde']
```

The above output is correct

Code 2:

```
def myfunc(e):
  return len(e)
x=[`ab', 'abc', 'aaa','abcd',abcde']
x. sort(key=myfunc)
print(x)
```

```
Output :[`ab', 'aba','aaa','abcd','abcde']
```

Here 'aaa' should come first why python is throwing this output

Please any one can explain

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can simplify your code right off the bat with `x.sort(key=len)`, which is a lot more explicit than wrapping `len()` with the unclearly named `myfunc()`. Anyway, since the order of the list was changed, the second output is expected. You're sorting on `len`, length, so there's no alphabetizing going on within groups of the same length. Are you trying to sort each length group alphabetically?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819012/how-does-python-break-tie-when-sorting-an-iterable

Comment: It's different in both the cases please check

Comment: Yes I'm trying to sort alphabetically

Comment: sort functions does not change the relative order of elements that compare equal.
So results that you get are correct (assuming 'abc' not 'aba' in the second result).
And why do think that 'aaa' should come first?

Comment: You put length of string as criteria for sort. Why it should be sorted  alphabetically?

Comment: Hi what if I write X. Sort(reverse=False,key=myfunc)

Answer (score 0):

It is a stable sort. Your key is same for both of them. so the output is same as your input in this case.